# showing error while using the "using" statement in wcf application

Tags: .net, wcf

I have following code

```
 using  (AdventureWorksEntities database = new AdventureWorksEntities())
```

But it is showing that

'New_WCF_App1.AdventureWorksEntities': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

How to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error message is reasonably clear - `AdventureWorksEntities` doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface. It can't be disposed, so you can't use it as the resource in a `using` statement.

Next you need to work out whether it *should* implement `IDisposable`, or whether it really doesn't have any resources to dispose.

EDIT: According to comments, with Entity Framework 4 this should work without any extra implementation, as the auto-generated code already implements `IDiposable`.

Comment: This is incorrect. The new entity model will auto generate and it will implement IDisposable auto-magically.

Comment: @bugnuker: It's correct for the question - if the OP were using the new generator, presumably they wouldn't have had the problem at all, would they? When you say "new" - you did notice that this question and answer were both in February 2011, right?

Comment: 2011 should have been entity 4, and this was working in 2011. I guess it all depends on Codefirst/Database first and what version the user was using. At anyrate, as of today, with current Framework, add reference to the corrent Entity dll. - I'm not trying to rain on your accepted Answer. I came to this page today due to me needing to find the correct answer for todays technology. If a user is using old entity framrwork, your answer could surely work for someone. Anyone who has updated, will need the updated answer.

Comment: @bugnuker: I'll certainly edit - but it strikes me that anyone who has updated won't run into this as a question in the first place. They should already *have* a reference to the relevant assembly, as otherwise I'd expect a whole heap of other errors.

Comment: Ah, yes. If everything is in the same project, your are 100% correct. However, in my case, My entity Model project is separated from the business logic that uses that model. The BLL project needs a reference to the entity project and that entity DLL to work.

Answer (score 6):

Such an error when using the `using` statements for data contexts in WCF most likely means that you are missing the reference to the `System.Data.Entity` assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to System.Data.entity (like krzysztofkarolczak said) (below 5.0) or EntityFramework.dll (entity 5.0) and this will solve your problem.